# Calculation on gearbox design

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, gears, applied-mechanics, mechanical

I want to design a gearbox of 70hp input motor and speed of 1400rpm. The gearbox ratio is 1:10 of 2 stage parallel arrangements.
How do I calculate for the teeth, modules and other requirements necessary to design the gears, shaft and casing.
Though i know how to calculate gear teeth but not relating to gearbox from the power given. Thanks

Comment: Could you give more info regarding stall torque of motor and whether you wish for the gearbox to fail or release prior to it?  Calculate forces on your gears to do structural analysis.

Comment: Motor specification-Torque is 356.35Nm, power 70hp. Gear ratio 1:10. Input shaft diameter 1.5" output shaft diameter 2". 2 stage parallel arrangements. What do I need to do to design the full gearbox which includes gears,shaft and casing. I already designed one using SolidWorks but not sure if it will withstand load. I don't wish for it to fail.

Comment: Torque produces a force (more accurately a pressure) on each gear and shaft.  Note that both a radial (bad) and tangent (good) component may be present thanks to friction.  Use CAD to help assist in figuring geometry extremes for lever arms to points of contact as teeth hand off from one set to another.  I'd use both max motor torque as well as energy from sudden stop (include effects of all mass including payloads) from max speed to check if individual teeth or shafts risk shearing off.